# Recoding multiple variables based on condition of one variable

Tags: r

I want to recode multiple variables (circa 90 of them) based on a value in another variable.

Here's a sample:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,0,5,10,0), var2 = c(1:5), var3 = c(1:5), var4 = 
c(1:5), var5 = c(1:5), var6 = c(1:5), var90 = c(1:5))

df

  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var90
1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
2    0    2    2    2    2    2     2
3    5    3    3    3    3    3     3
4   10    4    4    4    4    4     4
5    0    5    5    5    5    5     5
```

When var1 = 0, I want to recode var2 to var90 as 0, otherwise leave them as they are.

I can recode a single variable easily enough using:

```
df[df$var1 == 0, c("var2")] <- 0
```

And I can apply this over multiple columns using numeric notation:

```
df[df$var1 == 0, c(2:7)] <- 0
```

Which does the job nicely on this little sample set, this is the expected result:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var90
1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
2    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
3    5    3    3    3    3    3     3
4   10    4    4    4    4    4     4
5    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

However, on my full dataset (~90 variables, 90,000 rows) I had to abort after about 20 minutes because it still hadn't run (hoping to get this to run in seconds rather than minutes).

Any ideas of how to go about this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `set` from `data.table` to make this faster

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(j in 2:7) set(df, i = which(df$var1 == 0), j = j, value = 0)
df
#   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var90
#1:    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#2:    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#3:    5    3    3    3    3    3     3
#4:   10    4    4    4    4    4     4
#5:    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

---

In addition, we can use `lapply` from `base R` to avoid creating a big logical matrix

```
df[2:7] <- lapply(df[2:7], function(x) replace(x, df$var1 == 0, 0))
```

Comment: I think a bracket is missing below.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var2:var90), funs(ifelse(var1 == 0, 0, .)))
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var90
1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
2    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
3    5    3    3    3    3    3     3
4   10    4    4    4    4    4     4
5    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: Boom! This works a treat. Can you explain what the last dot means in funs()? (I checked the help text but I don't get it)

Comment: It refers to whatever is in the vars part; in this case second to last variable which should be kept as they are.

Answer (score 3):

We can use some maths as well

```
df[2:7] <- df[2:7] * +(df$var1 != 0)

#  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var90
#1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#2    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#3    5    3    3    3    3    3     3
#4   10    4    4    4    4    4     4
#5    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

We convert `var1` into 0, 1 for values which are equal to 0 and not equal to 0 respectively and then multiply those values with rest of the columns so 0 values become 0  whereas non 0 values stay as it is.